# How to best copy large folders?

Tags: copy, cp

I want to copy 1 TB of data from 1 HDD to another via Terminal.

What is the best approach to this?

So far, i've used the following, but I've no idea, whether it actually makes progress, or if it just froze the window:

> sudo cp -r /mnt/CloudDrive1 /mnt/CloudDrive2

Comment: Command looks ok. This will take a loooooong time USB device to USB device.

Comment: You can use verbose flag `-v` to know what is being copied, assuming you have multiple files in the drive

Comment: Search this site for "slow copy" -- you have a worst case situation. Basically when writes are slower than reads, system buffers fill, and the system drags to a crawl.  Install and use "nocache" on whatever copy command you select to eliminate caching input blocks (might help a little).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `rsync`. It shows a progress bar, it has resume in case there is an error or you need to stop for a while.

Copy of a directory recursivly:

```
rsync -av --progress /mnt/CloudDrive1/ /mnt/CloudDrive2/
```

> `-a`  The archive mode behaves like the recursive mode but keeps all file permissions, symbolic links, file ownership, etc.
>
> `-v`   Verbose output. Displays the details of the transfer.
>
> `--progress` Displays the transfer progress during synchronization.